# variable having access to instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class BankAccount

  def self.create_for(first_name, last_name)
    @accounts ||= []
    @accounts << BankAccount.new(first_name, last_name)
  end

  def initialize(first_name, last_name)
    @balance = 0
    @first_name = first_name
    @last_name = last_name
  end

 def self.find_for(first_name, last_name)
    @accounts.find{|account| account.full_name == "#{first_name} #{last_name}"}
  end

  def full_name
    "#{@first_name} #{@last_name}"
  end

end
```

How does the method `self.find_for` works?. I am getting confused on how the `account` variable has access to `full_name` method?.

```
bankacc = BankAccount.create_for "Kevin", "Shane"
BankAccount.find_for("Kevin", "Shane")
puts bankacc.inspect
```

Comment: Why does that confuse you? `full_name ` is a simple instance method and `account` is an instance of `BankAccount`, so you can call the instance mehtod `full_name` on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it helps you to understand the concept if you split the file into two.

This class creates and keeps track of BankAccount instances:

```
class BankAccounts
 def self.create_for(first_name, last_name)
   @accounts ||= []
   @accounts << BankAccount.new(first_name, last_name)
 end

 def self.find_for(first_name, last_name)
   @accounts.find{|account| account.full_name == "#{first_name} #{last_name}"}
 end
end
```

This is just a dumb class which you can create instances of:

```
class BankAccount
  def initialize(first_name, last_name)
    @balance = 0
    @first_name = first_name
    @last_name = last_name
  end

  def full_name
    "#{@first_name} #{@last_name}"
  end
end
```

In `self.create_for` you are creating a new account and putting it into the variable `@accounts` which is "global" (a class variable) inside BankAccounts. Your new instance of a bank account is stored in `@accounts` so when you use `self.find_for`, it can look in `@accounts` to find it there.

`@accounts.find{|account| account.full_name == "#{first_name} #{last_name}"}` essentially means:

"Look into the `@accounts` Array, and for every account instance (that is, an instance of BankAccount) see if the full name matches. `full_name` is a method I may use to inspect a `BankAccount` instance."

Answer (score 1):

Because you code it like that.

Look the line `@accounts << BankAccount.new(first_name, last_name)`.

It means `@accounts` holds all `BankAccount` objects. Now `full_name` is an instance method of the instances of the class `BankAccount`.

Now in the below line -

```
 @accounts.find { |account| account.full_name == "#{first_name} #{last_name}"}
```

`#find` method passing each such `BankAccount` object(`account`) to the block, and `account` is calling the method `full_name`, being an instance of the class `BankAccount`.

Nothing wrong here.